# Javascript filter method not working with if and else if

Tags: javascript, object, filter

I have a object that contains multiple (10) objects.

1 object looks like this:

```
bracket: null
bracket_id: null
game_site: null
game_site_id: null
id: 88462
next_game_for_loser: null
next_game_for_loser_id: null
next_game_for_winner: null
next_game_for_winner_id: null
next_team_for_loser: 1
next_team_for_winner: 1
number_of_sets: 5
pool: Object
pool_id: 18739
pool_round: Object
pool_round_id: 21984
season: Object
season_id: 20167
start_time: "2013-03-04T13:00:00+01:00"
swiss_round: null
swiss_round_id: null
team_1: Object
team_1_id: 21202
team_1_score: 3
team_2: Object
team_2_id: 21206
team_2_score: 1
time_created: "2012-12-09T12:46:33.626319+00:00"
time_last_updated: "2012-12-09T12:46:33.626361+00:00"
timezone: "Europe/Amsterdam"
tournament: Object
tournament_id: 18519
winner: Object
winner_id: 21202
```

I want to filter the objects on matchups (team id's)

I filter like so:

```
var game = games.objects.filter(function (gameInfo) { 

            if (gameInfo.team_1_id == team1ID && gameInfo.team_2_id == team2ID) {
                return (gameInfo.team_1_id == team1ID && gameInfo.team_2_id == team2ID) && (inverted = 1);
            } 

            else if (gameInfo.team_1_id == team2ID && gameInfo.team_2_id  == team1ID) {
                return (gameInfo.team_1_id == team2ID && gameInfo.team_2_id  == team1ID) && (inverted = 0);
            }
        });
```

I got 2 variables to set the team id:

```
var team1ID = 21206;
var team2ID = 21202;
```

I want the filter function to return the specific object where it matches the teamID1 and teamID2. This works good if `gameInfo.team_1_id == team1ID && gameInfo.team_2_id == team2ID`
But when i invert it like so: `else if (gameInfo.team_1_id == team2ID && gameInfo.team_2_id  == team1ID)` Then the object `game` is always empty...Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(inverted = 0)
```

Here you are assigning, not comparing. The resulting value (`0`) will always be falsy, and the filter function will return an empty `game` array.

Also, you should check for the `inverted` flag first, and not duplicate the other comparisons unnecessary:

```
var game = games.objects.filter(function (gameInfo) { 
    return inverted == 1
      ? gameInfo.team_1_id == team1ID && gameInfo.team_2_id == team2ID
      : gameInfo.team_1_id == team2ID && gameInfo.team_2_id == team1ID;
});
```

If you want to set it, it should look like this:

```
var inverted;
var game = games.objects.filter(function (gameInfo) { 
    if (gameInfo.team_1_id == team1ID && gameInfo.team_2_id == team2ID) {
        inverted = 0;
        return true;
    } else if (gameInfo.team_1_id == team2ID && gameInfo.team_2_id == team1ID) {
        inverted = 1;
        return true;
    } // else
        return false;
});

// Shorter, using the comma operator:

var game = games.objects.filter(function (gameInfo) { 
    return (gameInfo.team_1_id == team1ID && gameInfo.team_2_id == team2ID && (inverted = 1, true)
        || (gameInfo.team_1_id == team2ID && gameInfo.team_2_id == team1ID && (inverted = 0, true);
});
```

Comment: yes the intention is to asign a value to 'inverted', when inverted = 1 i do something and when inverted = 0  i do something else. Later in my code.

Comment: I want to know when the TeamID's are inverted. So when gameInfo.team_1_id == team2ID && gameInfo.team_2_id == team1ID

Comment: I see. Still I'm not sure why you used the `filter` then

Comment: i the specific Object back (that matches the filter) and see if the teams are inverted or not.

Comment: Yes, my last two snippets do exactly that, don't they?

Comment: yes and i would thank you for that :) I was only answering your questions :)